# Sorting coordinates by 'enveloping' or 'dominance' criterion

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort coordinates in a vector based on whether they are enveloped or dominated by other coordinates. For example the coordinate `[1 , 2 , 1 , 1]` is enveloped or dominated by `[4, 2 , 1 , 2]` even though the 2nd and 3rd values of both coordinates are equal.

Highlight of program. (Complete program [online at rextester.com](http://rextester.com/TGRZ23774))

```
int input[18][4] = { { 4 , 3 , 3 , 3 } , { 1 , 5 , 4 , 1 } , { 2 , 4 , 5 , 4 } ,
                     { 3 , 1 , 2 , 5 } , { 4 , 2 , 1 , 2 } , { 1 , 3 , 3 , 1 } ,
                     { 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 } , { 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 } , { 5 , 2 , 1 , 2 } ,
                     { 1 , 4 , 4 , 1 } , { 1 , 1 , 2 , 1 } , { 1 , 2 , 1 , 1 } ,
                     { 2 , 1 , 2 , 4 } , { 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 } , { 3 , 1 , 1 , 2 } ,
                     { 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 } , { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 } , { 2 , 1 , 1 , 2 } };   

struct Coordinate
{
    Coordinate(){}
    Coordinate( int (&val)[4] );
    bool operator<( const Coordinate& otherCoord ) const;
    void print() const;

    int value[4];
};      

void print( const std::vector<Coordinate>& coord );

int main()
{
    std::vector<Coordinate> coord;
    coord.assign( input  , input + 18 );
    print( coord );

    std::sort( coord.begin() , coord.end() );
    print( coord );
}
```

Program output is however not what I expected,

```
[ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 1 , 4 , 4 , 1 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 ]
[ 3 , 1 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 1 , 3 , 3 , 1 ]
[ 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 ]
[ 2 , 1 , 2 , 4 ]
[ 1 , 2 , 1 , 1 ]
[ 1 , 1 , 2 , 1 ]
[ 4 , 3 , 3 , 3 ]
[ 5 , 2 , 1 , 2 ]  // <-- ???
[ 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 ]
[ 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 ]
[ 4 , 2 , 1 , 2 ]  // <-- ???
[ 3 , 1 , 2 , 5 ]
[ 2 , 4 , 5 , 4 ]
[ 1 , 5 , 4 , 1 ]
```

For example `[ 5 , 2 , 1 , 2 ]` envelopes or dominates `[ 4 , 2 , 1 , 2 ]` yet appears before it as shown in the program output.

Comment: There are ambiguous cases: `[1, 5, 4, 1] < [2, 1, 1, 2]` return `False` in your case. Should it be `False` or `True`?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is because there are cases where there no strict ordering criterion e.g. `[ 1 , 2 , 1 , 1 ]` and `[ 1 , 1 , 2 , 1 ]` do not envelope each other.

Comment: Please provide a formal definition for "envelopes"

Comment: @AndyG Roughly, envelopes means given two coordinates `A` and `B` of dimension `N`, `A` envelopes `B` if `A[i] >= B[i]` for at most `N - 1` pairs and `A[i] > B[i]` for at least one pair.

Comment: @Olumide: I think what you've described is [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). And if you change your code to more modern C++ you basically get it for free: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d4MzTeyvIJxwPWCa)

Comment: @AndyG Brilliant! I'll upvote if you post it as answer. Only problem tho is that the dimension of the coordinates can vary between problem instances.

Comment: Will do. Regarding dimensionality, I don't see how the existing impl is more flexible in that regard.

Comment: @AndyG  The dimension (or size) of `std::array` has a compile-time parameter.

Comment: @Olumide: But so do your arrays?

Comment: @AndyG That was just for example. I still think your answer is great, based on the information that I initially provided.

Comment: @Olumide: Fair enough. I presume you are using raw pointers and allocating as needed. That would allow some run time flexibility. You'd get the same or better performance with templates plus safety, at the cost of flexibility. Tradeoffs...

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) that basically amounts to saying the comparison `(x1, y1) < (x2, y2)` is equivalent to saying `if (x1 < x2 || (x1 == x2 && y1 < y2))`

The body of your `Coordinate::operator<` can be modified as follows:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
   if( value[i] > otherCoord.value[i] ) 
     return false; 
   if (value[i] < otherCoord.value[i] ) 
     return true; 
} 
return false;
```

We return `false` at the end because we are performing strict less-than comparison. When we've reached that line we know that all the elements of both coordinates are identical, so if we return true then we've satisfied `<=` instead.

However, I would propose that you update this code to use more modern C++. Namely vectors and arrays. This is nice especially because the default `operator<` for a `std::array` will perform lexicographical ordering for you. (Additionally you don't have to worry about pointer math because you get to use iterators).

Here is your new class:

```
template<size_t N>
struct Coordinate
{
    Coordinate(){}
    Coordinate( std::array<int, N> _val);
    bool operator<( const Coordinate& otherCoord ) const;
    void print() const;
    
    std::array<int, N> value;
};
```

And here's how you'd implement `operator<`:

```
template<size_t N>
bool Coordinate<N>::operator<( const Coordinate<N>& otherCoord ) const
{
    return value < otherCoord.value;
}
```

And finally `main`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Coordinate<4>> coords;
    coords.assign( input.begin(), input.end() );
    print(coords);
    std::sort(coords.begin(), coords.end());
    print( coords );
}
```

Prefer the templates for `Coordinate` so that you can make coordinates of arbitrary dimensionality at compile-time. Right now there is a lot of [magic numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) going on to make it all work.

### [Here's a live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d4MzTeyvIJxwPWCa)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer and I'm posting here for posterity's sake.

**The sorting criterion must define [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which is defined by the following four properties**

Accordingly I've re-implemented `operator<` as follows.

*Note: implementation intentionally suboptimal for sake of clarity. (Comparisons should ideally be done once and cached.)*

```
bool Coordinate::operator<( const Coordinate& otherCoord ) const
{
    int ltCount = 0;
    int gtCount = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        if( value[i] < otherCoord.value[i] ) ++ltCount;
        if( value[i] > otherCoord.value[i] ) ++gtCount;
    }

    if( ltCount == 4 ) return true;     // Strictly less
    if( gtCount == 4 ) return false;    // Strictly greater

    // Neither stritcly greater or less. Create ordering (based on magnitute of first coordinate)
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        if( value[i] == otherCoord.value[i] ) continue;
        return( value[i] < otherCoord.value[i] );
    }

    return false;   // this should NEVER happen if coords are NOT equal.
}
```

Comment: BTW, now, you just have lexicographical ordering (Strictly less/greater is handled by next comparison).